# How to avoid creating transparent parts when drawing text in PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Problem solved! thank you

```
draw.fontmode="1"
```

After adding the above option, anti-aliasing was turned off and the text came out all white with no irregular colors.

---

Please understand that I used a translator so my question may be inaccurate.
The screen is drawn using PIL and output to the Led Matrix.
However, when I write letters, there are some parts around the letters that are slightly blurred. How can I eliminate this phenomenon and make them all white?
Please refer to the photo below. The source code for loading the font is attached below the photo.

[image]

(It's hard to see in the photo, but the blurry part of the text is clearly visible on the border.)

```
...
self.font14 = ImageFont.truetype(font_path14, 14)
...
```

I searched, but couldn't find any related articles.

Comment: I guess it's due to some sort of antialiasing, have a look at the doc, maybe you can disable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it is caused by [anti-aliasin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_rasterization)g, You can choose whether you want it or not like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# Create empty black image and get drawing context to it
im = Image.new('RGB', (600,300), 'black')
dctx = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

# Load a TrueType font, antialiasing is enabled by default
font = ImageFont.truetype("/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Academy Engraved LET Fonts.ttf", size=64)

# Disable antialiasing
dctx.fontmode="1"
dctx.text((20,60),"Without antialias", font=font, fill="white")

nColours = len(im.getcolors())
print(f'Without antialising: {nColours=}')

# Enable antialiasing
dctx.fontmode="L"
dctx.text((20,160),"With antialias", font=font, fill="white")

nColours = len(im.getcolors())
print(f'With antialising: {nColours=}')

# Save result
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

**Output**

```
Without antialising: nColours=2
With antialising: nColours=255
```

---

In terms of clarity, you will notice it is smoother and easier to read with anti-aliasing (just look at the initial `W` and see how jaggy it is without antialiasing), but that also introduces more colours/shades of grey into the image which may be undesirable at times.

---

Here's a close-up:

[image]